# Return a column of 'days in month' from monthly index Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time series of monthly values and I would like to calculate the number of days in that month (to then divide the number by to get a daily average for that month).

I have used `calendar.monthrange()` to calculate this by looping through the values, but I was looking at the `pandas.DataFrame.apply` method (https://medium.com/@rtjeannier/pandas-101-cont-9d061cb73bfc) and wondering how it was possible to use that instead of a loop?

The code below gives me the output I would like, but for efficiency (and learning) purposes I'd like to understand the better way of doing this by using the apply method rather than a loop.

```
import pandas as pd
import calendar

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['temp'] = pd.date_range(start='01-Jan-2000', end='31-Dec-2018', freq='MS')  
df['value'] = 5
df.set_index('temp', inplace=True)

days_list = []
for val in df.index:
    days_list.append(calendar.monthrange(val.year, val.month)[1])

df['days_in_month'] = days_list
```

I can find the number of days for one row of the index nice and easily by using this:

```
calendar.monthrange(df.index[0].year, df.index[0].month)[1]
```

But then if I tried to do it for a number of values (see below) it throws an error, I am missing the methodology on how to get between the two.

```
calendar.monthrange(df.index.year, df.index.month)[1]
```

The end goal would to create a column (like the loop does) but more efficiently and without the needless creation of a list, looping through, then adding the list to the dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `map` with `df.index`:

```
df['days_in_month'] = df.index.map(lambda val: calendar.monthrange(val.year, val.month)[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

How about getting the index column to a regular column and then using `daysinmonth`:

```
df['days_in_month'] = df.index.daysinmonth
```